# Commands in Python IRC bot built with oyoyo

Tags: python, frameworks, command, irc

I have recently found the [oyoyo](https://code.google.com/p/oyoyo) Python IRC framework and as it looks decent from my newbie perspective, I have chosen to build an IRC bot with it (Twisted seems a bit daunting). I have looked at the [example](https://code.google.com/p/oyoyo/wiki/OyoyoExample), but I am not sure how I would implement more commands. Would I just have a lot of if statements in the privmsg function? And how would trigger these if statements? While I am not a complete noob, I am still a newbie, so please don't judge me if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IRC bot in twisted](https://web.archive.org/web/20120505020602/http://www.habnabit.org/twistedex.html) demonstrates how your bot can respond to several commands.

You define several `command_*()` methods and call them from `privmsg()` method.

`getattr(self, 'command_'+command_name, None)` retrieves appropriate method to call.

Comment: Alright, it seems that I will have to try Twisted. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @user1008773: you could try Twisted. But `getattr()` doesn't require Twisted.

Comment: @j-f-sebastian Ah, so that part was for oyoyo?

Comment: @user1008773: no. It is a plain Python, see [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr).

Comment: @j-f-sebastian Ah, okay. Well, thanks! Now I don't have to learn a whole new, and quite advanced, framework. I will probably look into Twisted in the future though, it seems cool.

Comment: this link is broken :(

Comment: @polka: the original page is no longer available. I've changed the link to point to its archived version.